# Download partial file from Azure storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have files which are big in size. Since the file size is too large, I have been trying to download partial file from Azure blob storage.
I have been using `DownloadRangeToStream` method from class `CloudBlockBlob` and it works perfectly fine for me.

Now we are planning to use `Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlockBlobClient` for upload and there is not similar method in `BlockBlobClient` class which download file in range or blob block (Not the whole file but a block of it)

I was wondering if there is any other way to do the same in more optimized way.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you would want to use is [`Download(HttpRange, BlobRequestConditions, Boolean, CancellationToken)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.download?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_Specialized_BlobBaseClient_Download_Azure_HttpRange_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobRequestConditions_System_Boolean_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) which is in [`BlobBaseClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient?view=azure-dotnet) class (BlockBlobClient derives from this class).

[`HttpRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.httprange?view=azure-dotnet) parameter of this method is where you would define the offset and length.

Comment: Any blog where I can find the difference between `CloudBlockBlob.DownloadRangeToStream` and `BlockBlobClient.Download`. Which one is better to use for large and frequent data.?

Comment: These are two methods in different Storage SDKs.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code change to download big files in chunks (For Azure SKD v12).
All you have to do is call this method by passing your start point and length (or end point)

```
    public Stream DownloadRange(Stream outputStream, Guid containerName, Guid blobName, long offset, long length)
{
    var blockBlobClient = new BlockBlobClient(
                                    _configurationKeys.StorageConnectionString
                                    ,containerName.ToString(), 
                                    ,blobName.ToString());

    var httpRange = new Azure.HttpRange(offset, length);
    var output = blockBlobClient.Download(httpRange);
    output.Value.Content.CopyTo(outputStream);
    return outputStream;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the detail of the class [BlockBlobClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blockblobclient?view=azure-dotnet). To perform a partial update of the content of a block blob, use the [StageBlock(String, Stream, Byte[], BlobRequestConditions, IProgress, CancellationToken)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blockblobclient.stageblock?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_Specialized_BlockBlobClient_StageBlock_System_String_System_IO_Stream_System_Byte___Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobRequestConditions_System_IProgress_System_Int64__System_Threading_CancellationToken_) and [CommitBlockList(IEnumerable, BlobHttpHeaders, IDictionary<String,String>, BlobRequestConditions, Nullable, CancellationToken)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blockblobclient.commitblocklist?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_Specialized_BlockBlobClient_CommitBlockList_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobHttpHeaders_System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary_System_String_System_String__Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobRequestConditions_System_Nullable_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_AccessTier__System_Threading_CancellationToken_) operations.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: `StageBlock` method is more related to upload. I checked the page as well but couldn't find any method related to partial download.

Comment: @RahulKhandelwal you want to download, but upload?

Comment: I am looking for download. More precisely alternative of `CloudBlockBlob.DownloadRangeToStream`

Answer (score 0):

As the length that `blockBlobClient.Download(httpRange);` only returns 3118 bytes (may be some http limit) at one I got another solution. I download to a stram and set the position of the stream:

```
public Stream DownloadRange(Stream outputStream, Guid containerName, Guid blobName, long offset, long length)
{
    var blockBlobClient = new BlockBlobClient(
                                    _configurationKeys.StorageConnectionString
                                    ,containerName.ToString(), 
                                    ,blobName.ToString());

    var buffer = new byte[length];
    using (Stream s = blockBlobClient .OpenRead())
    {
        s.Position = offset;
        var pos = 0;
        while(pos < length) {
            var len += s.Read(buffer, 0, length);
            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, len);
            pos += len;
        }
        return outputStream;
    }
```